# Dynamic Type in iOS for interactive elements

Tags: ios, button, fonts, accessibility

I am currently implementing an iOS application with support for dynamic font sizes (for accessibility). I read Apple's documentation on the matter[1], and it states the following:

> The fonts returned using text style constants are meant to be used for
>   all text in an app other than text in user interface elements, such as
>   buttons, bars, and labels.

Why is that? Wouldn't it be particularly important to adjust elements such as buttons in an application, since those are the parts where the user interacts with the application? This becomes even worse when the user sets the dynamic type font size to something very large, because elements like buttons are even harder to see because everything else becomes so much bigger, but buttons stay at their 15pt font size.

I am interested in: What is the reasoning behind this? Should elements like buttons just stay at their default font size, how do others handle this?
Also, I am unclear on what exactly is supposed to be dynamic and what isn't - how about textfields, the label of a textfield or explanatory text (which is a label)?

[1] https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/CustomTextProcessing/CustomTextProcessing.html

Answer (score 2):

The Apple documentation flies in the face of the W3C WCAG 2.0 AA 1.4.4 Resize Text requirement which states "Except for captions and images of text, text can be resized without assistive technology up to 200 percent without loss of content or functionality. (Level AA)" (https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-WCAG20-20081211/#visual-audio-contrast-scale)

You are correct to solve for dynamic font sizes in interface elements.  I would disregard the Apple documentation.

Comment: I agree, but I still wonder about the reasoning behind Apple's documentation. Also, since the Cocoa APIs don't provide good support for this, it can be hard/impossible to "work the system" (say, by enlarging the buttons of a tab bar or navigation bar)

Comment: I don't think i'm a fan of "disregard the Apple documentation". The documentation is referring to the use of text style constants, not the general practice of accessibility. They are saying that their text style constants shouldn't be used in those places, thats just not where they engineered them to work i would guess.

Answer (score 0):

You need to subclass or extend UIButton, then add a Label as a subview.

```
class DynamicTextButton : UIButton{


var dynamicTextLabel: UILabel!

override init(frame: CGRect){
    super.init(frame: frame)

    setDynamicTextLabelAndConstraints()

    self.heightAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualToConstant: 0.0)
    self.adjustsImageSizeForAccessibilityContentSizeCategory = true
    self.backgroundColor = ButtonStyle.TextButtonColor_Background

}


required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}


private func setDynamicTextLabelAndConstraints(){

    dynamicTextLabel = UILabel(frame: frame)
    dynamicTextLabel.font = ButtonStyle.TextButtonFont
    dynamicTextLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    dynamicTextLabel.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .body)
    //self.textColor = TextStyle.MainTextColor_Normal
    dynamicTextLabel.adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory = true
    dynamicTextLabel.numberOfLines = 0
    dynamicTextLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping
    dynamicTextLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualToConstant: 0.0)


    self.addSubview(dynamicTextLabel)

    dynamicTextLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant:  0.0).isActive = true
    dynamicTextLabel.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor, constant:  0.0).isActive = true
    dynamicTextLabel.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor, constant:  0.0).isActive = true
    dynamicTextLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor, constant:  0.0).isActive = true

}

}
```

To use:

```
    var myDynamicButton = DynamicTextButton(frame: frame)
    myDynamicButton.dynamicTextLabel.text = "My Button Title"
    myDynamicButton?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```